# Is it possible to spin up a free development / test instance of an AWS Redshift server to run test queries on?

Tags: aws, redshift

I have a traditional MS SQL Server background and am interested in looking into AWS Redshift.

Microsoft offers a free download of their development version installer of SQL Server, and I was wondering if there's an equivalent for AWS Redshift so that I can run some test queries and check out the performance.

I don't expect an equivalent installer, I just meant an equivalently easy way to spin up a dev/test environment. I don't care if it's local or in the cloud, but hopefully there's a way to demo it without having to pay.

Answer (score 2):

Redshift is a service so you cannot run it locally unless you want to buy [AWS Outposts](https://aws.amazon.com/outposts/).

Nevertheless, you can try RS during Free Tier - [trial period](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/free-trial/). After that price can be as low as [$0.25 per Hour](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/pricing/) (+traffic+tax), billed hourly.